# Sitecore - where is shared content being used/displayed?

Tags: sitecore

Is there a way to see/report where a shared module of some kind is being displayed? For instance, if I have a list of links that I know is used on 20 pages but, I am not sure where, can I report on that node in the tree to see what pages are using it?

Comment: Could you be more specific what this 'shared module' is? Is this a type of sublayout, an item in Sitecore tree, ascx control, something else?

Comment: Its an item in the tree.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see which items link to specific item then you can run the Links report from the [Advanced System Reporter](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Advanced_System_Reporter.aspx). You can also generate your own reports to suit your needs.

[image: Links Report - Advanced System Reporter]

Answer (score 1):

If your list of links is held in an item in Sitecore, you can select the item within the content editor, select the 'Navigate' tab and click the 'Links' button. This will show you where the item is referenced.

If you are looking to see where a sublayout is used, the [Presentation Usage Reporter](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Presentation_Usage_Reporter.aspx) module is a really useful tool for showing this.  Note: In theory this can also be done with the above method (selecting the sublayout in question first) however the results are not very reliable...

Comment: Thats what I expected but, when I click "links" it only has a title of "References" and under that it tells me the type and template which was used to create the module not where it is being used. I know for a fact it is displayed in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either use the method mdresser is talking about, going to Navigate and clicking Links, but if it's used in a datasource field it won't show up. You could then use an XPath query for that, which would be something like `fast:/<StartLocationOfQuery>/*[@__Renderings = '%path of the datasource you're interested in%']`

Please note I've typed the query without testing it so there might be typo's and such.